# Getting more than 100 results with wikipedia readinglist API

Tags: json, wikipedia

I'm able to get my saved articles with this URL:

https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/data/lists/XXXXXX/entries/

XXXXX being the ID for the list, I'm able to get that id there, when I'm logged in:

https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/data/lists/

The problem is that I can only get 100 items in that json (on the first URL), and the last items is this:

```
next    "{\"rlecontinue\":\"2018-07-11T09:25:27Z|3322230\",\"continue\":\"-||\"}"
```

I have no idea how to paginate. Any clue?

EDIT:
I've tried

```
https://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=readinglistentries&rlelists=378020&rlelimit=100&rlecontinue=-||
```

but it returns `"code": "badcontinue", "info": "Invalid continue param. You should pass the original value returned by the previous query.",`

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/data/lists/XXXXXX/entries/?next=2018-07-11T09:25:27Z|3322230
```

but it returns

```
type    "https://mediawiki.org/wiki/HyperSwitch/errors/server_error#invalid_paging_parameter"
title   "Invalid paging parameter"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/data/lists/XXXXXX/entries/?next={"rlecontinue":"2018-07-11T09:25:27Z|3322230","continue":"-||"}
```

Just don't forget to remove escaping anti-slashes.